# CakePHP, Where to call method from

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a situation where I am wondering where the best place is to call a method in a model.

I have a method in the model called positionRecords(), this model loops through certain records and based on some criteria, it orders the records with a position field in a table.

At the moment I am calling it from the afterSave() method in the Model, but I don't want to call it every time a field is saved, like for instance, I have other methods that could be changing a date field, and this will also call the afterSave() method, and will then call the positionRecords() method, which will have no effect on the position of the record.

Is it in this case better to call the positionRecords() from the controller when the save was complete on an add and edit and delete? Or is it better to build conditions into the afterSave() method to determine when the positionRecords() should be called?

P.S. this is just one example, I am looking for the best practice when it comes to certain events like an edit, add or delete.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Call positionRecords when it is required and do not put anything in callback functions until unless it is required throughout your app.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

And best place to call model function is from Controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation